# kafka.utils.Time doesn't exist

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Environment pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.0</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.0</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Application code:

```
import kafka.utils.MockTime;

"""
 Time mock = (Time) new MockTime();
 kafka = TestUtils.createServer(kafkaConfig, mock);
"""
```

The problem is:

the createServer function from TestUtils need a Time class as second parameter, but there is no Time class in utils

which means

```
import kafka.utils.Time
```

will fail

if I use org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Time,

the TestUtils.createServer complains with

```
The method createServer(KafkaConfig, Time) from the type TestUtils refers to the missing type Time
```

How can a function needs a parameter of which the type class doesn't in its module ?

Comment: what do you mean by `there is no Time class in utils`?

Comment: @Natalia  kafka.utils.Time doesn't exist, there is no such class in this package

Comment: Is your code belongs to test suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something that implements `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Time` interface. Either `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime` or `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.MockTime`.

Transition from Scala to Java made some of the test utils dependencies slightly messy.

Comment: I'm guessing this MockTime is this.https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/utils/MockTime.scala . Do you know if it is pushed as some maven artefact?